# Using periods in enumerated lists

Tags: grammar, lists, periods

A couple of colleagues of mine pointed out to me that I should not end a list point with a period. For example:

> There a few things that I would like to address in the meeting:
>
> 1. We should focus more on the advertisement rather than sales reviews.
> 2. The dates and venue for the annual gala have to discussed and decided.

However, I have been told to not use the periods when making such lists or *when using checkboxes*. I find it weird.

Hence, I ask of you, what *should* be done? What is the accepted grammar?

Comment: Your colleagues are wrong. There is no problem with complete sentences in lists. You can even have multiple sentences in lists. But if one list item is a complete sentence, they should all be. In other words, the items should be consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason said in the  comments section:

> Your colleagues are wrong. There is no problem with complete sentences in lists. You can even have multiple sentences in lists. But if one list item is a complete sentence, they should all be. In other words, the items should be consistent.